# Windows 7 DO NOT refresh my dirs

Tags: windows-7

i have some serious problem with Windows Explorer. I created question about it, but i didn't narrow down the problem. My problem is that Windows Explorer refreshes the folders too slow - what i mean is this: Everything works perfectly, i delete a file and after refresh the file is still there, as you may imagine A LOT of programs crashes because of this behavior. All of them with IOExceptions i tracked the problem by Process Monitor and got this:

```
Explorer.EXE    2296    IRP_MJ_CREATE    *    DELETE PENDING    Desired Access: Read Attributes, Delete, Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
Explorer.EXE    2296    IRP_MJ_CREATE    *    DELETE PENDING    Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Requiring Oplock, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, AllocationSize: n/a
svchost.exe    664    IRP_MJ_CLEANUP    C:\Users\h4x0r\Desktop\ModEncryptor\ModEncryptor\bin\Release\ModEncryptor.exe    SUCCESS    
Explorer.EXE    2296    IRP_MJ_CREATE    *    DELETE PENDING    Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Requiring Oplock, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, AllocationSize: n/a
Explorer.EXE    2296    FASTIO_NETWORK_QUERY_OPEN    *    FAST IO DISALLOWED    
Explorer.EXE    2296    IRP_MJ_CREATE    *    DELETE PENDING    Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
Explorer.EXE    2296    FASTIO_NETWORK_QUERY_OPEN    *    FAST IO DISALLOWED    
Explorer.EXE    2296    FASTIO_NETWORK_QUERY_OPEN    *.DLL    FAST IO DISALLOWED    
Explorer.EXE    2296    IRP_MJ_CREATE    *    DELETE PENDING    Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
Explorer.EXE    2296    IRP_MJ_CREATE    *.DLL    NAME NOT FOUND    Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
Explorer.EXE    2296    FASTIO_NETWORK_QUERY_OPEN    *.DLL    FAST IO DISALLOWED    
Explorer.EXE    2296    IRP_MJ_CREATE    *.DLL    NAME NOT FOUND    Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
Explorer.EXE    2296    IRP_MJ_CREATE    *    DELETE PENDING    Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Requiring Oplock, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, AllocationSize: n/a
System 4 FASTIO_ACQUIRE_FOR_SECTION_SYNCHRONIZATION * SUCCESS SyncType: SyncTypeOther
System 4 FASTIO_RELEASE_FOR_SECTION_SYNCHRONIZATION * SUCCESS 
System 4 IRP_MJ_CLOSE * SUCCESS 
System 4 IRP_MJ_CLOSE * SUCCESS
```

This is "recorded" after the file is being deleted and this is what is preventing me from accessing it. LockHunter says that the process locking the file is System (no path, no other info). In the beging Windows Explorer is trying to delte the file, as you can see unsuccessful, notice the last 4 lines - System, after that every operation is possible with the file. How can i identify this process?

Now i remember that i used tweak do disable LastAccess but restoring it does NOT help. Can anyone help me out? This are not system files, ran the sfc - no problems, the files are not specific - basically every .exe/.dll behave like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out the problem - it was disabled Microsoft service, Program Compatibility and Application Experience. Enabling this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is very hard to diagnose without physically seeing the machine as you really need to get a feel for the problem to diagnose.

However, with the information you have given, if someone came to me with this I would narrow it down to Antivirus / Resident type scanners, malware protection and after this, possibly your hard drive could be dying.

Comment: No the hard drive is fine (i think - S.M.A.R.T says everything is fine), also i don't have any Antivirus/Malware software installed, and i scanned the computer with a anti-virus so its clean, a virus is not the cause for this. I'm searching for a tweaks that allows this behaviour - like LargeSystemCache or something familiar.

Comment: I never said a virus is the cause of this, I was saying AV software.. usually I see this when people have installed multiple incompatible engines.

Comment: Turned out that System (process) id 4 is locking my executables and dlls. So anyone have thought about this? Any MS service that do that?